# Subsetting a data frame for all the unique values of a row

Tags: r, frame, subset, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a data frame as:

```
id   value
1    "hi"
1    "hi"
1    "hi again"
1    "hi again"
2    "hello"
2    "hi"
```

Now I want to get a separate data frame for each of the distinct values in *id* column.

```
df1
    id    value
    1     "hi"
    1     "hi"
    1     "hi again"
    1     "hi again"
and df2 
    id    value
    2     "hello"
    2     "hi"
```

How to achieve this efficiently in R ?

I tried doing the for loop

```
 df <- data.frame(id=c('1','1','1','1','2','2'),value=c('hi','hi','hi again','hi again','hello','hi'))
 for (i in 1:length(unique(df$id)))  {
         df1 <- df[unique(df$id)[i],]
         print(df1)
     }
```

But the result is

```
id value
1  1    hi
  id value
2  1    hi
```

I understand that *apply* family does the same for every row in a data frame, but I am not able to use them in this situation. May be I am missing something obvious ?

Comment: try `split(df, df$id)`

Comment: @JayBlack that split but doesn't save separate data frame in separate objects. It looks like the code posted was meant to reach that.

Comment: @SabDeM it is better to have all dataframes in a list rather than having separate objects in the global environment.  For separate objects just wrap with `list2env` after naming the list elements

Comment: I am not saying what is better or not. I was just underlying what I though was the intent of Shiva.

Comment: @SabDem  I have other operations to achieve after subsetting the data, so either way (having a list of dataframes or different dataframes) is fine.

Comment: OP depending what is happening next in the analysis, this intermediate step may be consolidated into more efficient code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of the comments above, command to assign data frames individually added.

```
df_list <- split(df, df$id)
names(df_list) <- c("df1", "df2")
list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```